# how to make buttons selection dynamic

Tags: jquery

i have 3 dynamic buttons with the following IDs and also a hidden field for the eid value.

Button1_1746 and Hidden1_1746

Button1_1755 and Hidden1_1755

Button1_1779 and Hidden1_1779

```
<script src="myclasses/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="myclasses/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="myclasses/colorbox/colorbox.css">

$("#Button1_1746").click(function(){
    var eid = $('#Hidden1_1746').val();
$(this).colorbox({
    href:"exposeegenerator_einheiten.php?eid=" + eid, 
    iframe:true,
    innerWidth:850,
    innerHeight:800,
    opacity:0.1,
    overlayClose:false,
});
});
```

As you can seen in my script only one button (1746) works, how can i make it dynamic ?